# Batch - Load a path (text) from a text file into a variable

Tags: batch-file, text-files

In my code, I save a path to a folder inside of a text file. My goal now is to load that path again from the text file and use it to upload a modified version of the folder to the original location.

So far I have tried this, without success:

```
set savePath="more test.txt"
xcopy /e testFolder %savePath%
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the file path will be on the on the first line of the text file, then you can use the `set` command with the `/p` switch.

```
Set /p savePath=<test.txt
```

Comment: Wow thanks the only thing I was missing was the /p. I tweaked it around and now it works! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

`FOR` command can help you.

```
for /f %%a in (test.txt) do (set "savePath=%%a")
```

It will set `savePath` as the last line of `test.txt`